# Rails: undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this super simple code in my view:

```
<% @something.each do |something| %>

<% i = i+1 %>

<div class="row">
<div class="span1"><span class="badge untouched"><%= i %></span></div>
</div>

<% end %>
```

and get this error

```
undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass
```

I have the exact same code in another view and there it works!
However, I'm new to rails and you see what I want to do. Maybe there is a more common way to increment an integer within an each loop?
Where does this error come from?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: i is not defined. you're most probably using `each_with_index` in the other view and you use i as the index variable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, `i` must have a value before you can increment it.

```
<% i = 0 %>
<% i = i+ 1 %>
```

Comment: funny how easy that was - is there a reason why integers are not 0 per default? I'm used to that from other languages.

Comment: In ruby, a variable that is not yet started is always `nil`. When you say `i`, there is no way to know if that's an integer i believe.

Comment: In typed languages, you probably would say `Integer i` or `int i`, so the interpreter knows it is an integer and set it to zero.

Comment: While not directly my issue, this was very helpful in diagnosing what was happening. I had a date field that existed in 2 of 3 cases and because it was not set, I was getting a page-breaking error like this. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

i is not initialized,

instead of each use each_with_index as follow

```
<% @something.each_with_index do |something, i| %>

<div class="row">
<div class="span1"><span class="badge untouched"><%= i %></span></div>
</div>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Initialize variable i = 0

```
<% i=0
i = i+1 %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Define:

```
def nil.+ other; other end
```